# How can I remove any trace of the author meta tag

Tags: html, metadata

I deleted both of the author metadata in all html files but still appears while sharing the website. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sharing where? FB for example caches your pages and does not fetch page data on every share.

Comment: Yes on facebook, is there a way to refresh the cache?

Comment: Added a quick how-to as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sharing some page on Facebook, the FB servers will fetch the page the first time it is being shared and cache/save all necessary data.

If you want to update data that is associated with a specific URL, you will need to use [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). Input your URL and you will see "Scrape Again" button. Click it.

[image]